# Hide or fold stash section automatically in magit-status

Tags: magit

I tend to stash a lot when using git, so my "stash" section in magit-stashes is getting pretty long. I'm not running out of hard-drive space or anything, so I don't want to delete the stashes. Can I make it so that when I open up magit-status, they're automatically hidden (as if you'd pressed tab while over the "Stashes" heading)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new `magit-section-initial-visibility-alist` option for that purpose.

```
(add-to-list 'magit-section-initial-visibility-alist '(stashes . hide))
```